# How to fit a standalone Tikz image in a two-column layout without compromising the font size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, standalone

Consider the following standalone Tikz dummy image, this file is named `tikfig.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    \draw    (402.75,174.41) -- (438.25,174.41) ;
    \draw    (438.25,174.41) -- (457.75,159.41) ;
    \draw    (441.25,122) -- (441.72,166.5) ;
    \draw [shift={(441.75,169.5)}, rotate = 269.4] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
    \draw    (402.25,274.5) -- (490.25,274) ;
    \draw    (488.75,274.5) -- (508.25,259.5) ;
    \draw    (493.75,121.5) -- (493.75,266) ;
    \draw [shift={(493.75,269)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
    \draw   (651.75,167.41) -- (651.75,271.09) .. controls (651.75,286.5) and (628.92,299) .. (600.75,299) .. controls (572.58,299) and (549.75,286.5) .. (549.75,271.09) -- (549.75,167.41)(651.75,167.41) .. controls (651.75,182.83) and (628.92,195.33) .. (600.75,195.33) .. controls (572.58,195.33) and (549.75,182.83) .. (549.75,167.41) .. controls (549.75,152) and (572.58,139.5) .. (600.75,139.5) .. controls (628.92,139.5) and (651.75,152) .. (651.75,167.41) -- cycle ;
    \draw    (465.25,175.25) -- (549.25,175.5) ;
    \draw    (508.75,273.5) -- (549.75,273) ;
    \draw    (80.6,85.2) -- (138.5,85.75) ;
    \draw    (81,173.6) -- (137.5,174.16) ;
    \draw    (80.5,274.54) -- (138.5,274.54) ;
    \draw    (81.6,21.4) -- (81.5,59.6) -- (81.5,274.54) ;
    \draw   (81.45,21.4) -- (90.45,39) -- (72.45,39) -- cycle ;
    \draw    (137.5,78.25) .. controls (137.5,72.73) and (141.98,68.25) .. (147.5,68.25) -- (191.5,68.25) .. controls (197.02,68.25) and (201.5,72.73) .. (201.5,78.25) -- (201.5,92.25) .. controls (201.5,97.77) and (197.02,102.25) .. (191.5,102.25) -- (147.5,102.25) .. controls (141.98,102.25) and (137.5,97.77) .. (137.5,92.25) -- cycle  ;
    \draw (169.5,85.25) node   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{40.46pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    ISMR
    \end{center}
    
    \end{minipage}};
    \draw    (137.75,167.5) .. controls (137.75,161.98) and (142.23,157.5) .. (147.75,157.5) -- (191.75,157.5) .. controls (197.27,157.5) and (201.75,161.98) .. (201.75,167.5) -- (201.75,181.5) .. controls (201.75,187.02) and (197.27,191.5) .. (191.75,191.5) -- (147.75,191.5) .. controls (142.23,191.5) and (137.75,187.02) .. (137.75,181.5) -- cycle  ;
    \draw (169.75,174.5) node   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{40.46pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    RF-FE
    \end{center}
    
    \end{minipage}};
    \draw    (138.5,267.13) .. controls (138.5,261.6) and (142.98,257.13) .. (148.5,257.13) -- (192.5,257.13) .. controls (198.02,257.13) and (202.5,261.6) .. (202.5,267.13) -- (202.5,281.13) .. controls (202.5,286.65) and (198.02,291.13) .. (192.5,291.13) -- (148.5,291.13) .. controls (142.98,291.13) and (138.5,286.65) .. (138.5,281.13) -- cycle  ;
    \draw (170.5,274.13) node   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{40.46pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    RF-FE
    \end{center}
    
    \end{minipage}};
    % Text Node
    \draw (169,197.63) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {.\\.\\.};
    % Text Node
    \draw    (417.5,57.5) .. controls (417.5,51.98) and (421.98,47.5) .. (427.5,47.5) -- (511.5,47.5) .. controls (517.02,47.5) and (521.5,51.98) .. (521.5,57.5) -- (521.5,111.5) .. controls (521.5,117.02) and (517.02,121.5) .. (511.5,121.5) -- (427.5,121.5) .. controls (421.98,121.5) and (417.5,117.02) .. (417.5,111.5) -- cycle  ;
    \draw (469.5,84.5) node   [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{68pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
    \begin{center}
    Software triggering system
    \end{center}
    
    \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to put this image in a main LaTeX file whose template is in two column. I tried the following:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includestandalone{tikfig}
\caption{Flowchart ...}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

I want to fit this standalone image in a two-column layout without compromising the font size. Command options such as `\includestandalone[width=.4\textwidth]{tikfig}` is undesirable as the image font size gets too small:
[image]

I want to maintain the image font size the same as the text font size. Moreover, I don't wanna touch in the Tikz file as it would be a painful task.

Comment: Use the starred form `figure*` to display the figure outside the two columns.

Comment: @jlab I don't wanna to display outside the two columns. As the title says, I want to display inside it.

Comment: You only tell us what you *don't* want to change, but you obviously need to change *something*. So think about what that could be. You could decrease the space between the two parts of the picture or you could increase the font size inside the picture. I would create the picture in such a way that it fits the column width in the first place. You know the width of the column, so just make sure that you drawing is not wider.

Comment: By the way, I think that the code of your drawing could be improved a lot. For example, there is no need to place a `center` environment inside a `minipage` inside a node when you just want to put four letters. And then there are parts in the drawing that are not really drawn due to `opacity=0`.

Comment: I could rewrite everything from the scratch, but as I said: I really don't wanna do so. Tikz is painful. I just want to rescale to fit it into one of the columns without making the font too small.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Regarding the quality of the Tikz code, that is a dummy example, you shouldn't care about this quality. It is being used for example purposes only.

Comment: Whether Ti*k*Z is difficult of not is surely a personal opinion. The simplest (but not necessarily the optimal) way to achieve what you want would probably be to increase the font in the TikZ picture (put `\large` or `\huge` or another font-scaling command right after `\begin{document}` in the stand-alone document) and then to scale the picture back so it fits the width of the column. But I have to admit that it is still a bit unclear to me in which direction the answer to your question should go.